# Ethernet Protocols (Modbus TCP/IP & Ethernet/IP) can be in the same network and in a ring topology without problems?

Tags: switch, switching, lan, topology

Ethernet Protocols (Modbus TCP/IP & Ethernet/IP) can be in the same network and in a ring topology without problems?
Please, refer to the attached drawing.
[image: Managed Switches Architecture]

What are the equivalent Cisco Switches for the Stratix 5700 Switches?

Regards,

Jose

Comment: Ethernet does not actually work in a ring. STP will create a single loop-free path. Ethernet does not care what upper-layer protocols it carries; it can carry IP, and IP can carry any number of transport protocols, like TCP. What you need to understand is how the network layers work, and also that to get from one network to a different network requires a router.

Comment: Define "Modbus" - it can be a dedicated, serial infrastructure or run on top of TCP/IP, possibly over (dedicated) Ethernet.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

At a high level, yes the protocols are compatible.  As long as everyone follows the Ethernet standard, you can use multiple protocols. IP can carry TCP, MODBUS or others.

But your diagram suggests you may have other problems.  As has been pointed out, spanning tree will create a loop-free path.  In the event of a failure, it will take a few seconds to reconverge.  That may or may not be acceptable to your system.

Also, you've created a single layer 2 domain.  while that isn't bad in itself, it means there are more things to go wrong that may affect your whole system.  Your IP addressing needs to be a single subnet for all your devices.

In my experience, some industrial devices (MODBUS) have trouble when there are lots of other devices on the network. They sometimes are sensitive to broadcast frames. If that's the case, you will need to add routers to create multiple subnets.